# How to export-import MLFlow experiments with original experiment ID using mlflow-export-import?

Tags: mlflow

I am using https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow-export-import to export experiments from local `mlruns/` to a RDS Postgres. However, for each new imported experiment, the experiment ID is not sequential. It is the sum of all runs and experiments imported before.

For example:

```
ID   0: Default, 0 runs
ID   1: Experiment 1, 88 runs
ID  90: Experiment 2, 86 runs
ID 177: Experiment 3, 1 run
ID 179: Experiment 4, 10 runs
```

Since the experiments ids can not be setted mannualy, there is a way to change the mlflow-export-import code to use the original experiment id? Or, at least, use incremental experiment ids for each new imported experiment?

Answer (score 0):

Experiment IDs are auto-generated by MLflow. There is no API to set or change them. In open source MLflow they are monotonically increasing integers, in Databricks MLflow they are UUIDs.

Comment: Hi, Andre! Thank you for the answer. Using postgres with open source is the same thing that use Databricks MLFlow or this happens because I am using the mlflow-export-import library? I have never used Databricks MLFlow, do not know the specificities.